# How to handle PermissionError using shutil module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I get `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\VERX\\Desktop\\New folder\\Files'` when I try to move a file how to handle this error?

I am very new to programming excuse my bad script.

```
import os, shutil

path = "C:\\Users\\VERX\\Desktop\\New folder\\Files"
directory = []
files_names = []
for files in os.listdir(path):
   file_name, file_type= os.path.splitext(files)
   directory.append(file_type)
   if file_type in os.listdir(path):
         file_full_name = file_name+file_type
         files_names.append(file_full_name)


for file_ext in directory:
   if not os.path.exists(path+"\\"+file_ext):
      try:
         os.makedirs(path+"\\"+file_ext)
      except FileExistsError:
         break

for files in directory:
   shutil.move(path, path+"\\"+files)
```

Comment: Do you have access to the directory? Also why do you have `path = f"C:\\Users\\VERX\\Desktop\\New folder\\Files"`, did you mean to use `r` instead of `f`?

Comment: What is the write way to write paths in windows? isn't like this? I started programming one week ago. correct me if it is not the way, I have access to the directory yes.

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy: An `r` prefix would not be necessary since all the backslashes have been doubled. Having an `f` prefix isn't necessary, but doesn't cause a problem since it contains no `{}` characters.

Comment: @martineau oh so that how it works thank you very much.

Comment: VERX: The right ways are either `"C:\\Users\\VERX\\Desktop\\New folder\\Files"` or `r"C:\Users\VERX\Desktop\New folder\Files"`.

Comment: The error appeared when I used shutil.move().

Comment: @martineau yes I have adjusted my path.

Comment: I think the `shutil.move(path, path+"\\"+files)` may be what's wrong. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this script?

Comment: @martineau I am trying to identify files extensions at the path then create folder for each extension then move each file to the folder according to it's extension. I found other ways doing this but I wanted to do this this way for me to learn..

Comment: The problem is that when `shutil.move()` is called, it ends up trying to do (for example) an `os.rename("C:\\Users\\VERX\\Desktop\\New folder\\Files",  "C:\\Users\\VERX\\Desktop\\New folder\\Files\\.txt\\Files")` which is, of course, impossible — you can't rename a folder to be inside itself — but, for some reason, Windows classifies it as a `PermissionError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have minor adjust @martineau code and it works good now.

```
import os, shutil

path = r"C:\Users\VERX\Desktop"

directories = []
file_names = []
#Create list of file extensions and file_names.
for entry in os.listdir(path):
    entry_r = os.path.join(path, entry)
    if os.path.isfile(entry_r):
        file_names.append(entry) # to get full name of the file
    entry = os.path.join(path, entry)
    if os.path.isfile(entry):
        file_ext = os.path.splitext(entry)[1]
        if file_ext:
            if file_ext not in directories:
                directories.append(file_ext)

# Make folder for each extension.
for file_ext in directories:
    dir_path = os.path.join(path, file_ext)
    os.makedirs(dir_path, exist_ok=True)

# Move file according to it's extension.
for src in file_names:
    file_ext = os.path.splitext(src)[1]
    src = os.path.join(path, src)
    dst = os.path.join(path, file_ext)
    shutil.move(src, dst)
```

Comment: I don't understand why my version with the `os.path.isfile(entry)` check wouldn't have worked yet this version without it — what you changed — does. I think not having it could cause problems in some circumstances, so suggest you figure out why having it in fails when it should not.

Comment: if os.path.isfile(entry):>> os.path.isfile(path)
Return True if path is an existing regular file. and entry is not path it's just a string coming from the path.. that causing it to false output everytime.. I will test my code more to see how it goes. I also removed if file_type: because I tried to print out something after this line and it never print anything it seems it's always false..

Comment: Thanks, that information helped me find the problem — see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version of your code that should work. I've changed several of the variable names to better reflect what they actually contain and added a few comments to explain what the code is doing.

```
import os, shutil

path = "C:\\Users\\VERX\\Desktop\\New folder\\Files"

directories = []
file_names = []

# Get list of file names and all unique file extensions.
# Ignores files without extensions.
for entry in os.listdir(path):
    entry = os.path.join(path, entry)
    if os.path.isfile(entry):
        file_name, file_type = os.path.splitext(entry)
        if file_type:  # Does it have an extension?
            if file_type not in directories:  # That hasn't already been seen?
                directories.append(file_type)
            file_names.append(entry)

# Create destination directories if necessary.
for file_type in directories:
    dir_path = os.path.join(path, file_type)
    os.makedirs(dir_path, exist_ok=True)

# Move each file to the proper directory.
for src in file_names:
    file_type = os.path.splitext(src)[1]
    dst = os.path.join(path, file_type)
#    print('moving {!r} to {!r}'.format(src, dst))
    shutil.move(src, dst)
```

Comment: I suggest stripping the leading dot and ignoring an extension that ends with a space, i.e. `file_type = file_type[1:];` `if not file_type or file_type[-1:] == " ": continue`. Add the same step when moving files. (It's not conventional in Windows to begin a directory name with a dot. For trailing spaces, normally the OS automatically strips them when creating a file or directory. I'd rather leave such a file in place rather than change the name. Retaining it requires using "\\?\" extended paths.)

Comment: @Eryk: I left the leading dot in because the that's what the OP was doing — it may not be a Windows convention it's perfectly permissible. Am also not too worried about file extensions with trailing space characters, don't think I've ever encountered one. Besides, the main purpose of my answer was to show OP the basic logic of doing what they want, not write the ultimate bullet-proof utility that handles every contingency. Although your code review will no doubt be useful to those wanting to do so.

Comment: Trailing spaces and mixed-case concerns (e.g. ".Txt") generally stem from files created on removable media in another OS such as Linux or macOS. Nowadays with Windows 10, with WSL and support for case-sensitive directories, I think at least some developers are starting to come across these problems more frequently -- but not average end users.

Comment: @Eryk: Good points, esp about the potential for mixed-case issues.

Comment: if os.path.isfile(entry): always output an false... this cause an empty list...

Comment: @Eryk: True...removed. Didn't notice when testing because `os.path.join()` produced the desired result anyway — an undocumented "feature" `;-)`